# Alternatives to passing around a context object

Tags: c#

I have a single context object that I want to be able to access from a large number of difference classes. I have code that looks like

```
Context ctx = new Context();
Section section = new Section(ctx) {
    Data1 = new SomeData(ctx) { Value = 123 },
    Data2 = new SomeOtherData(ctx) { Foo = "bar" },
    SubSection = new Section(ctx) {
        MoreData = new MoreData(ctx) { Text = "Hello!" }
    }
};
```

But what I'd really like is code that looks like:

```
using(Context.New()) {
    Section section = new Section() {
        Data1 = new SomeData { Value = 123 },
        Data2 = new SomeOtherData { Foo = "bar" },
        SubSection = new Section {
            MoreData = new MoreData { Text = "Hello!" }
        }
    };
    // do something with section
}
```

Is this possible? I'll be using it in ASP.NET as well as .exes (and probably something else in the future) so I can't just store a `static` or thread local reference somewhere.

It doesn't need to be exactly as above, just a way where I won't have to pass the context to every object I create. I thought about using extension methods like `context.createSomeData()` but it requires more boilerplate per class and isn't really any better as you still need the context object.

Ideally should work under VS2008/.NET3.5, although I'd still be interested if there's any way to do it at all.

**UPDATE**: I ended up solving this by refactoring my approach into the following:

```
Section section = new Section {
    Data1 = new SomeData { Value = 123 },
    Data2 = new SomeOtherData { Foo = "bar" },
    SubSection = new Section {
        MoreData = new MoreData { Text = "Hello!" }
    }
};
section.DoStuffWithContext(new Context());
```

While it may not work for everyone, it does what I need here.

I'll leave this question open in case someone comes up with a good solution to the initial problem.

Comment: Would `new Section(ctx) { Data1 = new SomeData { ... }, Data2 = new SomeOtherData { ... }, ... }` be good enough? If so, you could change your `Section` class's property setters to pass the context to the assigned values.

Comment: That's a good point, although that would be _a lot_ of boilerplate. I want others to be able to make classes which extend these classes; the current mandatory one-liner constructor is easy enough but having to define complex setters for every property would be a bit much.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a static method `Context.RetreiveData()`, but you don't have to implement any boilerplate code inside of the method itself.

Using command pattern every specific project type can provide its own implementation for the `RetreiveData()` method. ASP.NET project can supply a method that would retreive data from Session. WinForm executable can supply a method that would retreive a data from some global variable. Yet another project can supply a method for retrieving data from DB.

Comment: This breaks decoupling and encapsulation to a point I'm not comfortable with in this particular project. Given .exe A, and .dlls B and C, where A has a reference to B and B has a reference to C - when `Context` is defined in C then we'd need to implement this additional code in A. This may seem overly pedantic but the way we're using and distributing these libraries it won't be feasible. Good idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

No. There isn't any clear possibility. You are even using object initializers (`new Obj { ... }`), so you need to use the `new` operator (this makes using static methods/extension methods of ctx impossible).

The only thing you could do:

```
SomeData MakeSomeData(this Context ctx, int value)
{
    return new SomeData(ctx) { Value = value };
}
```

and in the initialization:

```
Context ctx = new Context();

Section section = new Section(ctx) {
    Data1 = ctx.MakeSomeData(123), ...
```

but I don't think you would gain anything

Comment: Yeah, and the data types are quite sparse so I'd need to define potentially tens of arguments into the extension methods of which I'd use one or two. The invocation wouldn't be bad if I used named arguments (requires VS2010), but as you said, I wouldn't really gain anything.

Answer (score 0):

I second **hvd**'s comment on your question, and I don't think it would require too much boilerplate. Suppose each class implements this:

```
public interface IContextConsumer {
    Context Context { get; set; }
}
```

And your base class has a method like this:

```
protected void AddChild(IContextConsumer child) {
    child.Context = this.Context;
}
```

The property implementations would only need to be:

```
private SomeData _data1;
public SomeData Data1 {
    get { return _data1; }
    set {
        _data1 = value;
        AddChild(_data1);
    }
}
```

You could even allow the context to be reassigned on the root, if you did something like this:

```
protected void AddChild(IContextConsumer child) {
    Children.Add(child);
    child.Context = this.Context;
}

protected void OnContextChanged() {
    foreach (var child in Children) child.Context = this.Context;
}
```

Derived classes would just need to call `OnContextChanged` in their `Context` property implementations.